# How to get the absolute path of assets folder in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to modify the images in the assets  in the Controller.

```
def Test
   picpath=ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("images/1.jpg")
   file=open(picpath)
   ....
end
```

but the picpath is relative path which is ("/assets/images/1-232434.jpg") in the production environment.

I need the absolute path of the images.

The problem is the assets path is public/assets in the produciton environment,but the assets path is app/assets in the development environment.

How can I get the absolute path of the images so that I can operate the images?

Comment: That isn't what the assets folder is for; it's for serving *static* assets. You shouldn't be doing anything with the images in there except serving them. Things like user-uploaded thumbnails do *not* go in the assets directory.

Comment: which directory should I put the images if I want to change them?I just want to modify some pictures and display them on the website

Comment: If you want to modify images, you should do that by hand, and put the *static* images in the assets directory.

Comment: But I need the absolute path of assets folder,how can I get the path in the production environment,thank you !

Comment: You don't. Put the images in another directory, outside `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset folder depends on the environment as you said so you get the right folder in both cases.

If you have pictures as attachments, for example, I suggest something like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).
If you have to upload pictures you can use for example [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

If you want you custom solution I would store the pictures in a subfolder in the public folder like public/custompics. In this case you can access a picture at the relative path /custompics/1.jpg

Comment: which directory should I put the images if I want to change them?I just want to modify some pictures and display them on the website

Comment: If the pictures are related to active records I really suggest you take a look to stuff like paperclip.
I cannot imagine a context for what you are asking (maybe we need more info) but if I understand correctly, you want to edit a few static pictures and save them back in their original folder (overwriting the original files). Am I right? In that case, why don't you save them back in picpath? What picpath is, depends on the environment and that is correct anyway.

Comment: My context is:a picture like 1.jpg ,users modify 1.jpg then he will get 2.jpg,then this 2.jpg should display on the website and 2.jpg which only  this user can access.

Comment: In this case I suggest you use a subfolder in the public folder such as /public/custompics so you can access the pictures at the relative path /custompics/1.jpg .
I edited my answer to incude this.

Comment: But if in the /public/custompics,all uses will access the pictures.I hope only special use can access their special picture.

Comment: Then I really think you should take a look to Carrierwave. There is a tutorial in Railscast about it:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Answer (score 1):

**Assets**

When you use `assets` in ROR, you basically have a [series of helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) which allow you to call resources from the `asset pipeline`

As stated in the comments, your `asset pipeline` (& accompanying helpers) have been created in such a way as to help you load the files you require, whenever you need them (whether they're in the `assets/...` folder, or the `public/assets` folder

To access assets, or images, regardless of which folder they're in, or if they've been [fingerprinted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark), you'll be able to use the likes of [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) or [`image_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path) to load them successfully:

`asset_path "path/to/asset"`

--

**Images**

As stated in the other answer, you'll be best using something like [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to help manage your image uploads.

If you're allowing users to upload images, a system such as Paperclip will allow you to organize their uploads into a database, and then call the image through ActiveRecord:

```
#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
Class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @images = Image.all
   end
end

#app/views/images/index.html.erb
<% @images.each do |image| %>
   <%= image_tag image.attachment.url #=> reference to Paperclip %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But I want to directly access the assets folder,in the production environment,the assets is in the public folder.How can I get the assets path in the production environments? Like Application.config.something?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? It's against convention - so will likely cause problems in the future unless you have a robust reason for it

Comment: I thought it would be simpler,but now it is more difficult.

Comment: Well what's the core of the issue? I understand you want to access the `assets` folder directly, but *why*?

Comment: My app is picture processing,and these pictures should display on the website after process by ruby.So my solution is save it to the assets,because it looks more easy.

Comment: Hmm well even the gems save the images in the `public` folder - perhaps this would be a method you'd wish to adopt?

Comment: But if save the images in the public,all users can access these pictures.